# Checking the contents of a table cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table in my page and I'd like to use a while loop to check the contents of the first column of the code. This what what my code looks like. The name of my table is "list".

```
        var row=1;
        var cell=0;
        var flag=true;
        while (flag){
            var ele = list.rows[row].cells[cell].innerHTML;
            var stuff = ele.toString();

            if (stuff.search("Live") > -1 || stuff.search("Offline") > -1){
                row = row + 1;
            }
            else{
                flag = false;
            }
        }
```

and with the variable `i`, I can then go and modify stuff in that row specifically but for some reason I keep getting:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

When I try to run it and it`s not outputting properly. My table looks like this:

```
<table border="1" class="sortable" id="list">
<tr><th>Sort</th><th class="sorttable_nosort">Stream Name</th><tr>
<tr><td><script> livecheck("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel=gamespot", "True"); </script></td><td><a href="twitchtv.html" target="Stream">Twitch.tv test</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><script> livecheck("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=6815", "true"); </script></td><td><a href="own3d.html" target="Stream">own3d test</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><script> livecheck("http://xcornellheronsx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml", "true"); </script></td><td><a href="livestream(dot)com.html" target="Stream">livestream.com test</a></td></tr>
```

I have no idea why it`s not working.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your search function? WHAT do you get result from `livecheck()` method. Are you sure it is working? Would you like to share it for complete test of jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the variable `list.`

For example,

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#list');
```

Comment: well list is the name of my table so do i still need this?

Comment: Of course. `list` is a JavaScript variable, while `<table ... id="list">` is a DOM element. You need to get a JavaScript variable to point to the DOM element, before you can access the DOM element from JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, start by properly indenting your code. You'll see that your <tr> elements may be incorrectly nested (i.e. they all end up in the <th>) - http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/v8YdW/. Also, you probably want to pass "true", not "True". JavaScript is case-sensitive.